# Convert curves to meshes without adding points on straight lines

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices

I'm new here, so excuse my lack of knowledge.

I'll try to be straight.
Here is a sample of what I want to draw, I have something like 40 of them :
[image: A 3D mesh extruded from a curve]

My starting point is an svg curve.
Imported it in Blender, it looks like that:
[image: A curve in blender generated from svg curve. It owns less than 50 vertices]

Then I convert it to a mesh and, at this point it looks like that:
[image: The same curve converted into a Mesh. It owns hundreds of vertices]

I then remove some vertices by hand that seams unnecessary. After the removal, the mesh looks like that:
[image: The same mesh after I manually removed unnecessary vertices]

I understand the vertices that are on the curvy parts of the mesh are necessary, but maybe the ones on the straight parts are not.

Maybe I'm wrong to do this simplification, but I have the feeling, that making changes on the shape is easier with less vertices/faces. And maybe it's faster to draw too, I'm not sure.

Anyway, the removal operation is painful and slow. And I want to fasten then process, as I have multiple shapes to draw.

Is there a way to do this faster ?

- Automatically remove those vertices ?
- Do not generate them at first place ?
- Automatically merge the faces once extruded ?

Additionally, it other non-destructive simplification could be automated. Any kind of advice ?

Thanks a lot for reading even if you don't have any help to provide.

Comment: You can change the number of vertices that are created between curve control points by altering the resolution of the curve in object data/shape/resolution/resolution preview U.  I don't believe there's any way for Blender to distinguish between vertices that are important and that aren't important.  You're right, in general, that it's better to create fewer vertices than more.

Comment: what Nathan says, also you can press x > limited dissolve